# Замена всех None в запросе на пустую строку Python

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, flask

При запросе в базу, пустые ячейки преобразуются в None и так же отображаются на странице.
Мне нужно заменить каждую ячейки с None на пустую строку.
Вот кусочек имеющегося кода с запросом

```
        for id in tpaList:
        cursor = self.connections['DB_Name'].execute(f''' SELECT *
                                                            FROM [DB_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name]
                                                                AND EndDate IS NULL
                                                            ORDER BY StartDate DESC ''')
        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            idleJournal.append(dict(zip(columns, row))) 
    return idleJournal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сгенерировать новый список, заменив `None` на `''`:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    row = ['' if x is None else x for x in row]
    idleJournal.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
```

Или при генерации словаря:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    idleJournal.append({k: ('' if v is None else v) for k, v in zip(columns, row)})
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: @Arteil, пожалуйста :)